# Variance/Standard deviation of an observable on a state that is a linear combination of eigenvectors of that observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, superposition, observables

I know that when measuring the standard deviation of an observable the result will be zero if the system is an eigenvector of the observable on which i want to calculate the standard deviation. But let's imagine a quantum state that is a linear combination of eigenstates of that observable, in this second case can we say that the variance is always different from 0?
As an example, consider a harmonic oscillator prepared in the state $(|\psi\rangle = a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle + c|2\rangle)$, where $(|0\rangle)$ is the first eigenvector, and so on. Can we say that the standard deviation or the variance of the Hamiltonian $H$ of the harmonic oscillator is different from zero when calculated on the state $(|\psi\rangle)$? Additionally, assume that (a), (b), and (c) are complex coefficients, and their sum modulus squared is 1.

Comment: What problem do you have in answering this question? This should just be evaluating $\langle \psi \vert A \rvert \psi\rangle$ for $\psi$ a sum of eigenstates of $A$, right?

Comment: As an example, consider an harmonic oscillator prepared in the state |v> = a|0> +b|1> + c|2> where |0> is the first eigenvector etc, can we say that the standard deviation or the variance of the hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator is different from zero when calculated on the state |v>? a,b,c are complex coefficients and their sum modulus squared is 1.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what problem you have in computing that standard deviation?

Comment: i computed it and resulted different from 0  while i know that for single eigenstates is always zero. I wanted to know if is a general property of quantum mechanics that when i have a superposition of eigenstates then the standard deviation is different from zero.

Comment: You computed the correct thing.. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind  The question seems pretty clear to me:  suppose the variance of an operator $\hat{A}$, when applied to a particular state $|\psi\rangle$, is zero.  Does this imply that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $\hat{A}$?

Comment: Exactly, and apart from this is it possible to obtain a 0 variance preparing a state in a superposition of eigenvectors of the observable A ?

Comment: Yes, the uncertainty of a hermitian operator vanishes if and only if the corresponding state is an eigenstate of that operator. There are several ways to see this. For example, (suppose $\psi$ is normalized), we have $\langle A^2\rangle_\psi\geq \langle A\rangle_\psi^2$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, with equality if and only if $A\psi$ and $\psi$ are linearly dependent, i.e. if and only if $ A\psi=a\psi$ for some $a\in \mathbb R$ (CS ineqaulity gives you $a\in \mathbb C$, but $\langle A\rangle_\psi =a$ must be real for hermitian $A$). Now the uncertainty vanishes if and only if equality holds.

Comment: @TobiasFünke:  That looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

The oscillator Hamiltonian is non-degenerate, but this property is not necessary. Without loss of generality, to be self-evident later, stick to a two-dimensional Hilbert space, assuming
$$
A|1\rangle = A_1|1\rangle, \qquad A|2\rangle = A_2|2\rangle,\\
\langle A_1| A_2 \rangle=0.$$

You proved that, for
$$
|\psi\rangle = \cos\theta |1\rangle + \sin\theta|2\rangle , \leadsto \\
\langle \psi | A |\psi\rangle = \cos^2\theta ~~A_1 + \sin^2 \theta ~~A_2,\\
\langle \psi | A^2 |\psi\rangle = \cos^2\theta ~~A_1^2 + \sin^2 \theta ~~A_2^2,~\implies \\
\langle \psi | A^2 |\psi\rangle -\langle \psi | A |\psi\rangle^2 = \cos^2\theta ~~A_1^2 + \sin^2 \theta ~~A_2^2 -   ( \cos^2\theta ~~A_1 + \sin^2 \theta ~~A_2)^2\\
=\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta ~(A_1-A_2)^2,
$$
which only vanishes when one has degeneracy, or one of the trig coefficients vanishes.

So, when your observable lacks degenerate eigenvalues, then, yes, vanishing variance implies your state is an eigenvector thereof. If you have degenerate eigenvalues, then you are in their subspace.
Tertium non datur: you  must be in an eigenvector of A.

You ought to be able to generalize this to an arbitrary-dimensional orthonormal eigenspace: you are diagonalizing a multivariable positive semidefinite quadratic form associated matrix.

Comment: @AlexM3020  Comfortable with the general argument?